# How to get records from table based on two other tables JPA

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

I'm trying to do something simple in JPA.

I have a table Businesses:

```
 BusinessId    name
------------  ------ 
     1         Joe
     2         bob
```

And table Products:

```
 productID     name
------------  ------ 
     1         Pen
     2         paper
```

Because they related as meny-to-many I created another table businessesHasProductID:

```
 BusinessId    productID
------------  ----------- 
      1            1
      1            2
      2            2
```

Now I want to select BusinessId and productID form businessesHasProductID where the name of BusinessId = 'x' and the name of productID = 'y'.

I built the tables and then I created the entity classes (from wizard in netBeans). I know how to get the "Businesses" table where Businesses.name = 'x' and I know how to get "Products" table where Products.name = 'y'. but I want to combine these results and get the IDs.

I tried to do :

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("
              SELECT b FROM businessesHasProductID WHERE b.BusinessId IN 
                  (SELECT t0.BusinessId FROM Businesses t0 WHERE t0.BusinessId = 'x')
                AND b.productID IN
                  (SELECT t1.productID FROM Products t1 WHERE t1.productID = 'y')
              ");
```

That's not worked. It complains that the IN contains invalid data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get all the `[bId, pId]` tuples that exist in the join table and for which the name of the business identified by `bId` is 'x' and the name of the product identified by `pId` is 'y'.

If so, the following query should do what you want:

```
select business.businessId, product.productId 
from Business business
inner join business.products product
where business.name = 'x'
and product.name = 'y'
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I meant. But actually the table businessesHasProductID has one more field "price". so I want to select from businessesHasProductID.

Comment: The it's even easier : select business.businessId, product.productId 
from BusinessHasProduct bhp inner join bhp.business business
inner join bhp.product product
where business.name = 'x'
and product.name = 'y'